# Error when updating p2 enabled RCP application in multiuser environment

Tags: eclipse, provisioning, p2

Is that possible to implement the update of my own p2 enabled RCP application in a way that it will function in multiuser environment. What I want to do is identical to eclipse, I want to have my application installed in a location that is read-only to the user. When the user runs, he gets his own writable location, usually under his home directory. The user can install additional features that are stored under this writable location. How is that possible to do. I tested my application and it doesn't work this way by default, my application tries to download updates fails and keep restarting.

Thank you in advance.

Ulyana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy your RCP app, follow the steps in [Eclipse multi-user installs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html) to create a configuration area that you can make read-only and then run as another user.

In theory it should be something like:

1. rcp.exe -initialize
2. make RCP application directory read-only

Comment: Thanks a lot, the link was very useful for me, I was searching for it for a long time.