# RCP P2 updates in multi-user environment from read-only installation

Tags: linux, eclipse-rcp, p2

I have created an Ubuntu package to install my RCP app. The installed files are owned by root. Is it possible for a user to subsequently install updates through P2? Documentation about [Eclipse multi-user installs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html) suggests that  it is possible, along with the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743803/error-when-updating-p2-enabled-rcp-application-in-multiuser-environment).

However, when I start up the application, it does not automatically check for updates as usual, and the Update Site that I had specified in `p2.inf` is not listed in the "Install New Software..." dialog.

Using the `-configuration` or `-data` runtime options did not help.

I can make it work with a hack by running `sudo chown -R <my_username> /opt/<my_app_installation>`. When I subsequently launch the application, it does properly check for updates on startup, and my update site is properly listed in the "Install New Software..." dialog. Certainly I would prefer that whatever data it is writing to that installation directory be instead written to the user's home directory.

---

**Supplementary info:**

Here is a list of files and folders that showed up in my installation directory only **after** the directory was given ownership by `<my_username>` and the program was run.

```
/opt/<my_app_installation>/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime
/opt/<my_app_installation>/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.app
/opt/<my_app_installation>/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi
/opt/<my_app_installation>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/profile.profile/1339896994308.profile.gz
/opt/<my_app_installation>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/profile.profile/.data/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.prefs
/opt/<my_app_installation>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/profile.profile/.data/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.prefs
/opt/<my_app_installation>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository
```

---

**More experimental results:**

Even with a writable (chown'd) installation directory, no files are placed there when the 
`-configuration $HOME/.my_app_files` runtime option is supplied.

Comment: Did you use the `-initialize` option on first run as user?  I believe that is required to place the files in the home directory as per your config.  After the first run, you shouldnt need that option any more.

Comment: I believe the `-initialize` option is intended to create config directories without actually launching the GUI application. On first launch, if you omit the `-initialize` option, the config directories will be created anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of limitation of p2 itself for share install. AFAIK there is no significant improvement in latest release Juno as well.

But a guy from Redhat is working on p2 install with RPM package, you can read his progress in his [blog post](http://eclipseandlinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/making-p2-working-with-rpm-last.html). The work and idea could be shared with Debian package.

Comment: Bugs [249133](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249133) and [358471](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358471) indicate that many people are struggling with this. It seems that what I want is not possible at this time.